# Textarea scrollHeight returning incorrect value

Tags: textarea

I have an example where I want to show the height of the text area based on the content.
I see a gap at the end, where the textarea height is more than the content.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nd6B3/55/

```
function autoheight(a) {
    $(a).height($(a).prop('scrollHeight'));
}
```